# HBase create region

Tags: hadoop, nosql, hbase, apache-phoenix

I want dynamically add splits to existing table before saving data with keys for new regions.
Is any way available for create HBase region for existing HBase table or Phoenix table with defined start-end region keys or part of keys?

Answer (score 0):

There is a "split" command in HBase shell.